# Knowing $R^2$ and sample size

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, regression-coefficients

[image]

So basically we know $R^2$ and the sample size. How to use these two conditions to find out the largest number of slope coefficient k? Plus in the hint, $K$ is supposed to be very small and we could ignore it. Then why can't we just say that $k=K-1=-1$?

Comment: Beware that K is very small compared to N, but K and k aren't small compared to 1.

Comment: Got it, but do you know how to solve problems like this? I always have no idea how to use $R^2$.

Comment: Short hint: go to the formulas for $R^2$ and the F statistic. See that you can compute F from $R^2$, N and K. Use that F-test p-value is 5% to get F, and then you should be able to estimate K.

Comment: @Pere Could you also take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243927/regression-model-and-restrictions. I've been stuck at that problem since yesterday... but nobody offered any help. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm afraid that question got deleted or the link is wrong. Anyway, I suggest adding "self-study" tags to your questions.